# Get featured posts with wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use wp query to get featured posts from current category, you know the option in wordpress where you can put star in wp-admin and it will feature that post, i figured out how to get current category ID or name, so i can include that in my query, but still can't find what key is to get featured posts from that cat. Do you guys know how to get these posts?

Regards

Comment: where do you see the star option? it is probably added by the theme or a plugin, WordPress by default does not have such functionality.

Comment: Sorry it appears that theme added that functionality, however each featured post have _featured key with value yes, but i dont know how to build query.